# Filter and map Promise with async

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, sequelize.js

I got promise object, that returned by *sequelize.findAndCountAll()*, and I wanna filter the object before mapping them.

Here's my code:

```
async function getCountTask(id){
    return await Tasks.count({
        where: {
            studentID: id,
            status: 'Done',
            grade: ['A', 'B']
        }
    });
}

let totalStudent = [];

await Promise.all(
    listStudent.filter(async (f) => {
        const count = await getCountTask(f.id); 
        if(count <= 3){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }).map(async (e) => {
        let obj = {};
            obj.id = e.id;
            obj.age = e.age;
            obj.status = 'Great';
            totalStudent.push(obj);
    })
)
```

My expectation **listStudent** contain 5 data, but after filter, it will only contain 3 data because 2 another didn't pass the condition. So for ther final result the **totalStudent** containing 3 data.

But what I got from the code above is, the **totalStudent** have data exactly like **listStudent**.
It's because it process the map first and then the filter, so the map process data that didn't filter yet.

How do I can make it become filter first and then map the data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not doing a mapping operation with `.map`, you are doing a simple iteration. But I'm confused - what is `listStudent`? Is it an array of promises? A promise? If so, you have to `await` it first (or use the Promise API) or use `Promise.all` before you can filter/map. If `listStudent` is not a promise, I'm not sure what this code is doing. Filtering and mapping doesn't really work with `async` functions.

Comment: listStudent is a promise object, it's returned from sequelize. I did `await Promise.all()` above. Or you mean like `const lStudent = await Promise.all(listStudent);` and then map the lStudent? It's also not working

Comment: `filter(async (f)`  that will not wait, in fact your filter will always return a promise, and a promise is always true..

Comment: `await Promise.all` will await the promise returned from `Promise.all`. And if `listStudent` is a promise itself, then you're trying to use the promise *as if it's already resolved* and pass it to `Promise.all`. I'd suggest reviewing promises and async code.

Comment: @VLAZ Thankyou for the knowledges, yes I think I should do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter / map etc, don't support `async` in the way your using them.

eg. filter expects either a true or false, your returning promise `async` functions is always a promise.

```
await Promise.all(
    listStudent.filter(async (f) => {  <<<<---- This makes filter always return true
        const count = await getCountTask(f.id);
```

Looking at your code, a simple solution is just remove the filter, and just use map..

eg..

```
await Promise.all(
    listStudent.map(async (f) => {
        const count = await getCountTask(f.id); 
        if (count <= 3) return; //don't want this one.       
        let obj = {};
        obj.id = f.id;
        obj.age = f.age;
        obj.status = 'Great';
        totalStudent.push(obj);
    })
)
```

Seen as `Promise.all` returns an array, you can also avoid using `push` on `totalStudent`,.

eg.

```
totalStudent = await Promise.all(
    listStudent.map(async (f) => {
        const count = await getCountTask(f.id); 
        if (count <= 3) return; //don't want this one.       
        let obj = {};
        obj.id = f.id;
        obj.age = f.age;
        obj.status = 'Great';
        return obj;
    })
)
```

The advantage of the above is that the return order is also maintained.

Comment: Also even better is to *do a mapping operation* instead of misusing `.map` for a simple iteration. `return obj` at the end instead of pushing. If you're just doing an iteration, then `forEach` or use a loop.

Comment: Yeah, code above actually work. Thanks, so I know that the way I code above is not working. Thankyou :D

Comment: @VLAZ  In this case it's actually handy, as the promise gets pushed onto `Promise.all` ,  But yes, `return obj` would be good, and just assign the result of `Promise.all` to totalStudent.

Comment: @VLAZ  updated, so that `map` is doing something more meaningful, other than passing the promise to `Promise.all`

Comment: I wouldn't call it "handy" - it's still a misuse. `arr = await Promise.all(listStudends.map(getCountTask)); arr.filter().map()` is not misleading. With that said, `listStudends` is supposed to be a Promise, not an array, so I'm still confused what's actually happening.

Comment: @VLAZ  Not sure Op, say's this works, so I would assume `listStudent` is an array, not a promise.  Maybe he meant it's the return from a promise.  And would have got a big error of filter not defined it was.

Comment: Does this not insert `undefined` elements in the array?